# How to get input type 'file' variable on JQuery page and then pass variable and file to PHP page for upload

Tags: php, jquery

Image upload functionality is working fine using HTML, Javascript and PHP. But now I am trying to convert it into HTML, JQuery and PHP but I am not able to upload photo using below code.

I am not able to get file type variable on .js page and then file itself on php page (upload_p.php)

Please advise what I am doing wrong. I am trying to get this work for last 2 days but no luck yet.

**upload.php**

```
<form name="Uform" id="Uform" novalidate>
<div class="control-group form-group">
    <input type="file" name="img" id="img">
    <div id="success"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**upload.js**

```
$(function() {

$("#UForm file").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 

        // Try #1
        var form   = new FormData() ;
        var file = $('#img')[0].files[0];
        formData.append("file", file);

        // Try #2
        var FileData = $('#img').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', FileData);


        $.ajax({
            url: "./user/upload_.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {

                // Try #1
                upload : 1,
                data : file

                // Try #2
                img: img,
            },
            cache: false,
        })
    },
});
```

**upload_p.php**

```
$str_photo = "";
if(isset($_FILES['img'])) { $str_photo = trim($_FILES['img']['name']); }
.
.    
UploadFile($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"],$str_img_path);
.
.
SQL Query to insert data into database table
.
.
$response['status']='SUC';
$response['message']="Image uploaded successfully";
echo json_encode($response);
return;
```

Comment: Have you able to print data of $_FILES ?

Comment: You cannot upload a file using just jquery, use a plugin https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: also add the enctype='multipart/form-data'  in form tag , its best practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: @DiniZx, enctype='multipart/form-data' this is there in my code but I forgot to mention in question here. Also page is not submitted above both options I tried so not able to print $_FILES

Answer (score 0):

Use the below ajax code

```
.ajax({
    url: "./user/upload_.php",
    data: {

            // Try #1
            upload : 1,
            data : file

            // Try #2
            img: img,
        },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

After that try with

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

in your `upload_.php`

Comment: but with which option I should try your code? Are both options tried by me are correct? Please let me know.